# Select row from purchase table till sum of quantity not equal to available stock from stock table

Tags: mysql

`Purchase Table`

| id | itemId | storeId | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 10000 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-06 |
| 7 | 10000 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 |
| 6 | 10001 | 1 | 3 | 2023-02-04 |
| 5 | 10000 | 2 | 5 | 2023-02-04 |
| 4 | 10002 | 2 | 1 | 2023-02-03 |
| 3 | 10001 | 1 | 6 | 2023-02-03 |
| 2 | 10003 | 2 | 2 | 2023-02-02 |
| 1 | 10001 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-01 |

`Stock Table`

| itemId | storeId | available quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1 | 5 |
| 10000 | 2 | 2 |
| 10001 | 1 | 1 |
| 10002 | 2 | 1 |
| 10003 | 2 | 1 |

`Result I Want`

| itemId | storeId | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-06 |
| 10000 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 |
| 10000 | 1 | 2 | 2023-02-03 |
| 10000 | 2 | 2 | 2023-02-04 |
| 10001 | 1 | 1 | 2023-02-04 |
| 10002 | 2 | 1 | 2023-02-03 |
| 10003 | 2 | 1 | 2023-02-02 |

Comment: Use SUM() OVER () and compare this cumulative sum with stock quantity.

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL` ? Please tag only one. Please also explain the necessary logic to obtain the required result

Comment: MySql server @Squirrel